# Is "behavior" countable?

Tags: grammaticality

I wonder if "behavior" is countable. Is it? Can we say "He showed lots of unacceptable behaviors"?

Comment: Hello, user145781, and welcome to English language & Usage. Although your question seems reasonable, it has attracted a couple of close votes already, with both close voters noting the absence of any evidence of research on your part as the problem. Please consider strengthening your question by briefly outlining what you've found out on your own about whether _behavior_ is countable, and if possible indicate why you remain in doubt on this question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *behaviours* (plural) does exist, even by the dictionary definition:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/behaviours

> behavior (especially British) behaviour
>
> noun
>
> 1. manner of behaving or acting.
> 2. Psychology, Animal Behavior.
>
> observable activity in a human or animal.
>
> the aggregate of responses to internal and external stimuli.
>
> a stereotyped, species-specific activity, as a courtship dance or startle
>
> reflex.
>
> 3. Often, behaviors. a behavior pattern.
>
> 4.
>
> the action or reaction of any material under given circumstances: the behavior of tin under heat.

(see point 3)

Appropriate use:

The zoo allows us to study the *behaviours* of a variety of animal species in a controlled environment.

In your sentence, I would say the use of the word is appropriate as you seem to be enumerating the various distinct varieties of his bad behaviour. But I would probably lengthen the sentence to, for example: "He showed lots of unacceptable behaviours, including smoking, drinking and womanising." The longer construction seems less awkward to me.